# Unlimited value field in Drupal 7 module form

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-7, field

Trying to implement an unlimited value date field in a custom module form. I've been trying to follow the examples in a [blog post on unlimited item values in forms](http://rapiddg.com/blog/use-ajax-support-multiple-item-values-custom-drupal-7-forms) and [Drupal documentation on ajax forms](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056).

I've tried adding the equivalent of the `custom_registration_form` function code from the blog post above to my form builder function and ajax callback, but can't get additional date fields to show up when my ajax-enabled button is clicked. The `$form_state['storage']` data is available after clicking the save button for the form as a whole, but I can't tell if it's being used in the ajax callback properly.

Any ideas on implementing an unlimited value field in a module or links to examples would be appreciated. Unlimited fields seem like such basic functionality to Drupal's Field API, but I can't find any good examples of implementing this in custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried something like that but what if you do like this, you first create an unlimited field somewhere in a content type, then you var_dump or dpm $page['content']['system_main']['THE_FIELD']) you will see stuff like :

```
 '#process' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'file_field_widget_process_multiple'
```

and maybe get an idea how that field looks and implement it in your module